# iOS What's the difference between AddressBook.framework and AddressBookUI.framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook, addressbookui

I have to get email addresses from contacts, so I tried to add AddressBook.framework.
I found 2 similar frameworks.
 
What's the difference between AddressBook.framework and AddressBookUI.framework?
What should I use?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? They are totally different in nature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about asking someone else to consult the documentation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Address Book framework provides access to the contact information.

The Address Book UI framework provides the user interface to display the information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html